# Code improvement: Count the number of occurrences of elements in an array and return the most repeated element

Tags: java, kotlin, functional-programming, java-stream

I wrote both the implementation of IP and FP, but the implementation of FP feels some kind of wired.

First, impl of IP:

```java
public static int countThenMaxOf(int[] intArray) {
    int[] flags = new int[intArray.length];
    for (int i : intArray)
        flags[i]++;
    int indexOfMax = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < flags.length; i++) {
        if (flags[i] >= flags[indexOfMax])
            indexOfMax = i;
    }
    return intArray[indexOfMax];
}
```

Then FP version:

```java
public static long func(int[] intArray) {
    return Arrays.stream(intArray)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparingLong(Map.Entry::getValue))
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .orElseThrow();
}
```

As you can see, the stream is ***broke in half*** in the middle, This feels very unnatural.
In contrast, the Impl of FP in Kotlin is more beautiful:

```
fun func(intArray: IntArray): Int =
intArray.asSequence()
    .groupingBy { it }
    .eachCount()
    .maxByOrNull { it.value }!!.key
```

Don't mind my rough exception handling.

So my question is, can the implementation of Java `Stream` be improved? If so, how to do?

Am I missing something in `Collectors`?

Comment: For easier searching, finding the most common occurrence is called finding the mode of a list. And judging from the other stream implementations I could find online, this is about optimal.

Comment: how does `int[] flags = new int[intArray.length];for (int i : intArray) ){flags[i]++;}` even work? try for example, `intArray = {4,5,100};`

Comment: Oh, this is a simple exercise with some preconditions, I forgot to mention it. I mainly want to improve the FP implementation, thanks to Aplet223, I found what I want in that answer.